# Cannot install packages for foreign platforms

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy

I'm using a debian wheezy/sid, and it should support [multiarch](http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO):

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

However, I cannot install packages (I am [sure exist](http://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/zlib1g/download)):

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zlib1g
```

How can I install zlib1g for i386?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` [contains the requested architectures](http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Setting_up_apt_sources). It should look like

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main contrib
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```